# mod-rewrite условие для nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

Каким должно быть rewrite-условие для NGINX чтобы вырезать данные из ссылки:
http://srv1.domain.com/videofiles/XOprpsRlPIt_-EdMd5zl3w/1497640682/960x540/b6ae6a476b16409c2297f5c515.mp4

Требуется разбить ссылку на три части:
`XOprpsRlPIt_-EdMd5zl3w`  содержит `0-9 A-Z a-z - _`
`1497640682`   содержит `0-9`
`960x540/b6ae6a476b16409c2297f5c515.mp4`   содержит `0-9 a-z символ / и символ .`
и сделать переадресацию по адресу /realpath/$3?md5=$1&expires=$2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rewrite videofiles\/([\w\D]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([\w\D]+)$ realpath/$3?md5=$1&expires=$2 last
```